# Why does node.js need administrative permissions to access my windows share even though the share's premission is 0777

Tags: permissions, windows-8, sudo, shared-folders, nodejs

I have Ubuntu 14.04 running as a VMware guest on my Windows 8.1 host.

I have shared a folder on my Windows Host and it is mounted in the Ubuntu guest on startup using this entry in fstab:

```
//myhost/work /work cifs credentials=/home/user/.smbcredentials,noserverino,nounix,uid=user,gid=user,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0
```

Why is it that when using node in interact with the share, `sudo` is required?

For example, if I use `npm` to install something (`npm install --no-bin-links`) on the share without `sudo`, I get a bunch of `chmod` errors:

```
npm ERR! Error: EPERM, chmod '/work/project/src/node_modules/webpack/package.json'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EPERM, chmod '/work/project/src/node_modules/webpack/package.json']
npm ERR!   errno: 50,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   path: '/work/project/src/node_modules/webpack/package.json',
npm ERR!   fstream_finish_call: 'chmod',
npm ERR!   fstream_type: 'File',
npm ERR!   fstream_path: '/work/project/src/node_modules/webpack/package.json',
npm ERR!   fstream_class: 'FileWriter',
npm ERR!   fstream_stack: 
npm ERR!    [ '/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:308:19',
npm ERR!      'Object.oncomplete (evalmachine.<anonymous>:107:15)' ] }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /work/project/src/npm-debug.log
```

If I install it using `sudo npm install --no-bin-links`, everything works fine.

The same problem occurs when I use `gulp` to watch and build my project: `gulp watch` results in the same `chmod` errors when building, but `sudo gulp watch` works fine.

Since the share is set to `0777`, everyone is able to read and write to it. Why is it that I need to use `sudo` on node scripts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The folder is owned by a different user. Only the owner of the folder or root can change the permissions using `chmod`. Therefore, in my case, `sudo` is required as my user does not own the folder.